# Calculate relative frequency for a certain group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame of categorical variables that I have divided into groups and I got the counts for each group.

```
My original data nyD looks like:

Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: v1, v2, v3

  v1    v2   v3
1  a  plus  yes
2  a  plus  yes
3  a minus   no
4  b minus  yes
5  b     x  yes
6  c     x notk
7  c     x notk

I performed the following operations using dplyr:

ny1 <- nyD %>% group_by(v1,v2,v3)%>%
           summarise(count=n()) %>%
           mutate(prop = count/sum(count))


My data "ny1" looks like:

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: v1, v2

  v1    v2   v3 count prop
1  a minus   no     1    1
2  a  plus  yes     2    1
3  b minus  yes     1    1
4  b     x  yes     1    1
5  c     x notk     2    1
```

I want to calculate the relative frequency in relation to the V1 Groups in the prop variable. The prop variable should be the corresponding count divided by the "sum of counts for V1 group". V1 group has a total of 3 "a", 2 "b" and 1 "c".   That is, ny1$prop[1] <- 1/3, ny1$prop[2] <- 2/3.... 
The mutate operation where using count/sum(count) is not correct. I need to specify that the sum should be realed only to V1 group.
Is there a way to use dplyr to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this whole thing in one step (from your original data `nyD` and without creating `ny1`). That is because when you'll run `mutate` after `summarise`, `dplyr` will drop one aggregation level (`v2`) by default (certainly my favorite feature in `dplyr`) and will aggregate only by `v1`

```
nyD %>% 
   group_by(v1, v2) %>%
   summarise(count = n()) %>%
   mutate(prop = count/sum(count))

# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: v1
# 
#   v1    v2 count      prop
# 1  a minus     1 0.3333333
# 2  a  plus     2 0.6666667
# 3  b minus     1 0.5000000
# 4  b     x     1 0.5000000
# 5  c     x     2 1.0000000
```

Or a shorter version using `count` (Thanks to @beginneR)

```
df %>% 
  count(v1, v2) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: Or a bit shorter: `count(df, v1, v2) %>% mutate(prop = n/sum(n))`

Comment: Note that the order of the variables in the `group()` expression is also important and will determine how the relative proportions are computed.

Comment: Note that the original question had 3 groups; with 2 groups the answer fails to give relative frequences. However, the count version works with more than 2 groups.

Comment: @bshor What do you mean? Please provide an example

Comment: This is relatively helpful, but I think that it needs a more general solution to compute the proportions within groups e.g. for a questionnaire response you would want the percentage of men who answere a certain questions VS. the percentage of women who answered the same way.