# Calculate relative frequencies of factor levels in dataset

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Let this be my data:

```
my.data<-data.frame(name=c("a","b","b","c","c","c"))
```

What I need is a variable that indicates for each name, their respective relative frequency in the dataset. Essentially, this would look like that:

```
  name    target
1    a 0.1666667
2    b 0.3333333
3    b 0.3333333
4    c 0.5000000
5    c 0.5000000
6    c 0.5000000
```

What I tried is that I computed dummy variables for each name, and then based on these dummies I calculated new variables that indicate the relative frequency of each name in the dataset. See below:

```
temp_dummies<-data.frame(spatstat::dummify(my.data$name))
my.data<-cbind.data.frame(my.data, temp_dummies)
rm(temp_dummies)

my.data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(a_per=mean(a),
                b_per=mean(b),
                c_per=mean(c)) -> my.data
```

Now I need to extract the relative frequencies for each name and aggregate it back to get my target variable. I guess I should do something like this below but I don't know what to mutate.

```
my.data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(...) -> my.data
```

**Questions:**

1. How would I get my target variable using dplyr? Am I on the right track?
2. Is there an easier way to achive the same result?
3. Might it be possible to write a function that does all of this stuff automatically? It seems like a pretty standard problem that we should be able to fix by simply applying a `function(x)` to `name`.

Comment: @NelsonGon Strange that a clear dupe target that you commented got reopened

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676128/calculate-relative-frequency-for-a-certain-group or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll leave that question to you. Personally, I'd say it gets quite close to what my problem was but it's not a duplicate. But that's just me. ;-)

Comment: @akrun [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676128/calculate-relative-frequency-for-a-certain-group) strangely gives the same proportions as in this answer.

Comment: @FabianHabersack  `add_count` is simply a shortcut for `group-count-ungroup`.

Comment: @FabianHabersack Sure, `add_count` is as NelsonGon mentioned a group by frequency.  There are multiple dupes for this, but may not be the one with `add_count`  However, your question is not about `add_count` per se

Comment: @FabianHabersack  Also, this can be done in `base R` similar to KoenV's answer `prop.table(table(my.data))[as.character(my.data$name)]     a         b         b         c         c         c 
0.1666667 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000`

Comment: @NelsonGon To check the revisions of this post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56407446/revisions

Comment: @akrun Frankly, I think it's best to just let it go. Otherwise, the closing and reopening may go on. Just that closing a duplicate is somehow opinion based.

Comment: @NelsonGon @akrun I have closed this is dupe of the link posted. Sorry, I did not realise it earlier. It can be solved as `my.data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(count = n(), 
         count = count/sum(count))` from the dupe link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `add_count` to get count of each `name` and then divide it by number of rows using `n()`.

```
library(dplyr)

my.data %>%
   add_count(name) %>%
   mutate(n = n/n())

#  name      n
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a     0.167
#2 b     0.333
#3 b     0.333
#4 c     0.5  
#5 c     0.5  
#6 c     0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

With `base`-R, you could use the following one-liner:

```
my.data$target <- (table(my.data$name)/nrow(my.data))[ my.data$name ]
```

**Explanation** and in several lines of code:

we use the `table` function to get the number of occurrences of *name* and divide it by the number of rows in the df with `nrow`. After that you look up the "name" of the current row in the "table". This value is saved in the appropriate row of the new column.

```
t <- table(my.data$name)/nrow(my.data)
my.data$target <- t[ my.data$name ]
my.data

  name    target
1    a 0.1666667
2    b 0.3333333
3    b 0.3333333
4    c 0.5000000
5    c 0.5000000
6    c 0.5000000
```